# How to use fx:id for tab content in kotlin/tornadofx?

Tags: javafx, kotlin, fxml, tornadofx

Using the following code always ends with:

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property textArea has not been initialized
    at kam.applogviewer.main.LogTab.setContent(LogTab.kt:20)
```

It happens when I call `LogTab::setContent(lines)`.
Maybe this isn't the right way to use FXML with a tab in tornadofx?

MainView.kt (snippet):

```
class MainView : View("Example")
{
    ...

    fun showFileContent(fileName: String, lines: List<String>)
    {
        val logTab = LogTab(fileName, lines)
        tabPane.tabs.add(logTab)
        tabPane.selectionModel.select(logTab)

        // this call raises the exception
        logTab.setContent(lines)
    }
}
```

LogTab.kt:

```
package example.applogviewer.main

import javafx.fxml.FXML
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.control.Tab
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea

class LogTab(fileName: String, lines: List<String>) : Tab(fileName)
{
    @FXML
    lateinit var textArea: TextArea

    init
    {
        content = FXMLLoader.load(this.javaClass.getResource("LogTab.fxml"))
    }

    fun setContent(lines: List<String>)
    {
        textArea.text = "I like to see this text."
    }
}
```

LogTab.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<TextArea xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:id="textArea"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You load the FXML for the root node for the UI component using the `by fxml()` delegate and you access UI components generated from the FXML using the `by fxid()` delegate. You don't use the `@FXML` annotation in TornadoFX. You must also never instantate UIComponent instances manually, use `find` or `inject`.

Please read https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-guide/blob/master/part1/10.%20FXML.md for a complete explanation and also consider ditching FXML in favor of the much much better alternative: Type Safe Builders.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

How am I supposed to create new tabs for a tab pane when I should not create them manually? Could you please tell me what "find" you mean? I'm new to this and can't follow. Also how  can I use inject to create new tabs to be inserted into a tabpane?
Could you please elaborate on that a little more?

Comment: It is easy to define the user interface using builders, as you recommended. But I don't know how to apply this to the UI building of tabs (and not to a view). I mean, besides adding nodes.

Comment: Don't create Tab subclasses. Create Fragments and add them to the TabPane using the `add<MyFragmentClass>()`. The title from the Fragment will be automatically picked up by the TabPane.

Comment: Could you give a short example please?

Comment: There are examples of this in the guide, read chapter 7 (https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/part1/7.%20Layouts%20and%20Menus.html). Look for "Using UIComponents as tabs". You'll find a full code example there. I think it would be a good idea for you to read the guide from the beginning to get a better grasp of the framework.